# Set Winforms Tabpage Font Color without Custom Redrawing of String

Tags: c#, winforms, tabpage

Is there a way to specify the font color of a TabPage on a Winform?

I was expecting something like

```
tabControl1.TabPages["MyTab"].Font.Color = Color.Blue;
```

or something?

Comment: Google "msdn winforms tabpage color" -> [MSDN: Control.ForeColor Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.forecolor(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I wasn't looking to change the ForeColor of the TabPage, I was interested in changing the Font color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Is there a way to specify the font color of a `TabPage` on a Winform?* No, not without drawing it.

The property you are looking for actually exists..:

```
tabControl1.TabPages["MyTab"].ForeColor = Color.Blue;
```

..but it doesn't do what you hope for:  [TabPage.ForeColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabpage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) only sets the color for controls that are **nested in** the tabpage. ([Ambient property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.ambientproperties(v=vs.110).aspx))

The text you see at the top is part of the `Tab` control and color, font and backcolor are controlled via the `Tab` control only.

So, yes, you need to code the `DrawItem` event, where you can access the properties of each tabpage.

Comment: Thanks.  That is exactly what I thought.